# ASP.NET web config URL location authorisation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to restrict access to this URL using the location element code defined in my Web.config, but it doesn't seem to redirect the user when entering the URL directly in the address bar.

```
<location path="~/management/account">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Admin"/>
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Is this possible to achieve in Web.config? Or do I just use the Authorize + roles access definition attribute above the relevant function, for this particular scenario?

I've seen the location element used to restrict access to folders and specific pages, but have not come across one with URL routing?

Comment: The web.config is only one piece of the puzzle, you need to set authentication mode (ususally formsAuthentication), Membership and Role providers too. "Doesn't seem to work" tells us nothing. More information required to help.

Comment: I updated my question, however, adding this above my function `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use the authorization and/or location elements in an MVC app. To get authorization support in an MVC app apply the `[Authorize]` attribute on the controller level (then all actions requires authorization) or on the action level